# My SQL query using exception while getting data

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL to get data from table but it shows an exception. Here is the code I am using. I am calling this using URL to test:

```
    $userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userName']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserCredentials where UserName='$userName' ");
```

http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getUserData.php?userName=jamshaid.ali

Here is the exception

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getUserData.php on line 74 []
```

Here is the full code

```
   $userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userName']);

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserCredentials Where UserName='$userName' ");


    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
     ?>
```

Comment: that's not an exception its a lazy warning.

Comment: can you please explain how to resolve this

Comment: your query is breaking though you should add `mysql_error()` to get the error.

Comment: where is the section of code with mysql_fetch_assoc() in it?

Comment: can you post additional codes pls? where is `line 74`? where is `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: @Vivek posted full code

Comment: @JawAli `if( isset($_GET['userName']) ) { .... }`

Comment: jeeze do this `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserCredentials Where UserName='$userName' ") or die(mysql_error());` and post us the error

Comment: @swapnesh please edit in my code i am not getting this

Comment: Table 'productivo.UserCredentials' doesn't exist

Comment: table is in data base i do not why it is showing this errro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM UserCredentials where UserName='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userName']));
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(result){
   //do you code
}
```

Comment: of course, "Jaw Ali" query is syntactically invalid. So, mysql_query() fails and returns FALSE. more reference on here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions -

Use `isset()` , like --

```
if(isset($_GET['userName'])) {
// Do the processing, most appropriate check whether form is submitted or not
}
```

Now your code will looks like-

// Sanatize the data, and make sure to safe your code from sql injections(prefer PDO or mysqli_)

```
   if(isset($_GET['userName'])) {

   $userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userName']);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM UserCredentials Where UserName='".$userName."'";
   $query = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);

   }
 ?>
```

echo `$sql;` and run it in `phpmyadmin` to check your query is forming correctly or not, use var_dump() and read error/warning/notices to track errors.